# Qt scroll or resize main window

Tags: qt

I have an application, that is made for Full HD with Qt Creator. When now this application is opened on a screen with less resolution, the application is no more fully accessable and I'm not sure, what the best method would be to make still everything accessable.

So my first idea was to embed a scroll bar in the main window, but I don't like that and I would do this only, if no better method exists.

I would prefer to resize the whole application (all the fonts and buttons etc.) dynamically, but I found no way yet to do this. Is this even possible in Qt? If not, can I somehow move inside the application (for example drag the screen with the mouse) around, but without a scroll bar?

Comment: You can make your design such that width and height of all controls are connected to `QApplication::desktop()-&gt;screenGeometry().width()/some_ratio` and `QApplication::desktop()-&gt;screenGeometry().height()/some_ratio`

Comment: Hmm ok, but how can I connect the controls to this scale factor?